# How to make my iframe's javascript accessible to other sites?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

I am making a media player type application which other site developers can embed on their website. I need to provide them with a set of javascript functions which they can call from other parts of their website. I have a swf file in it with external interface hence I require it to be loaded in iframe.

How can I make the javascript inside my iframe to be accessible from outside?

I saw x-frame-options but it's allow-from directive does not work with chrome and safari. What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML5 way to do it is [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage).

If you cannot rely on its being used in an HTML5 environment, (a) that's really sad, and (b) you can use [Porthole](https://github.com/ternarylabs/porthole/).

Comment: That looks like a solution. I don't want to rely on HTML5 as already my application fails on mobile without flash. Can you tell how porthole works for browsers without support of postMessage?

Comment: [Here](http://ternarylabs.com/2011/03/27/secure-cross-domain-iframe-communication/) is a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you want to provide embeded code for your video player like youtube 
there is two option for that you can provide directly I-frame code to other website developers so they have to just paste the code in their page for E.g

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//website.com/videoid={videoid}" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

in Iframe Page target you can create your login and put your video code, html and javascript..

another option

if you want to go with javascript you they have to include your javascript into their page and in your javascript you have to implement login to create a `I-frame` using javascript and give iframe src dynamically ..

In that case you can definitely access your I-frame content using javascript beacause your javascript and I-frame belongs to same domain you can read more abour same orign policy
[**Same Origin**](http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy)

**EDIT:**
**HERE IS SOME EXMPLE CODE HOW TO CREATE I-FRAME USING JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>     
   var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');       
   document.body.appendChild(iframe);

   iframe.src = 'URL OF CONTENT YOU WANT TO PROVIDE';       
   iframe.width = 'THE WIDTH YOU WANT';
   iframe.height = 'THE HEIGHT YOU WANT';
</script>
```

Comment: I have gone the second way. However, browser does not allow script access to iframe from other domain. eg. window.frames[0].targetfunction() gives security  error in console. My scripts inside iframe are not accessible from the parent window

Comment: if your script and Iframe domain is same then you can access iframe too.. answer edited

Comment: That's what I assumed at first, but it didn't work out. Script's domain is taken to be the domain that embeds script not the origin of script. Hence, if abc.com embeds `src="xyz.com/script.js"` , the domain for _scripts.js_ shall be abc.com and it won't have access to iframe from xyz.com .

Comment: hmm here you make mistake you not neeed to provide javascript code to another website users .. you have to give your javascript source link for E.G if your server of video is  `www.abc.com ` then  `<script src='abc.com/js.js' ` and iframe is `<iframe src='abc.com\videoid="2" />`